# jQuery click doesn't work on html input

Tags: jquery

I have an input

```
<input type='text' id='email'/>
```

For some event I'd like to focus on that textbox

```
$('#email').click()
```

But this code doesn't work for some reasons (Chrome). How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: `focus()` perhaps?

Comment: focus doesn't work as well..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/64chq1jr/  Seems to work.

Comment: Do you have any other elements with the id of email? If so, then they might conflict with each other - ids are meant to be unique. Is the code executed after the element has been loaded? It would also be useful if you posted more of your script...

Comment: _some event_ can you define it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `click` you should use `focus()` to have a focus on the desired target element and make sure to wrap it inside doc ready block:

```
$(function(){ // <-------doc ready
   $('#email').focus(); // <----use focus event
});
```

Document ready ensures that DOM is ready and can be used. Either you wrap your js code inside this block or put the script at the bottom of the page. which runs when whole page gets loaded.

---

If you are using HTML5 then you might look into `autofocus` attribute:

```html
<input type='text' id='email' autofocus />
```